# how to fill canvas with a color

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to fill a color inside a canvas , this is my code :

```
Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(4.5f);
canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 30, paint);
```

This code makes a circle with a border color. How can I fill the circle with a color?

Comment: paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

Comment: Also one another same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934875/android-canvas-fill-background-color-canvas-application

Answer (score 17):

```
Paint paint2 = new Paint();      
paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
paint2.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
canvas.drawPaint(paint2);
```

You can make the following changes!!

Answer (score 6):

you need to set corresponding paint style for that, for example `Paint.Style.FILL` or `Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE`