# change background color and text color of paint in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I've searched the internet and found out that if we want to change the text color of paint I must use `setColor()`.
It also works for the set background too.
I want to change both text color and background when the user selects a special cell in my application.
`setColor()` is use for both?

this my code:

```
  Paint p = new Paint();

  case Connected:
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            p.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.intro_txt_cell_color)); // here I change background
        
            if (mGameCell.isFixed()) {
                p.setAlpha(140);

            } else {
                p.setAlpha(90);
            }
            drawBackground(canvas, 3, 3, mWidth - 3, mHeight - 3, p);
            break;
```

When I add set color again, it changes my background.
How can I change both text color and background?

Comment: check this it may help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934875/android-canvas-fill-background-color-canvas-application

Comment: If you want to draw a background shape with a specific color in addition to a text with another color, you should use two different `Paint` objects for them.